# Scala/DynamoDB - GetItems going very slow

Tags: scala, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I've a function that retrieves an item from DynamoDB (app and dynamo are running on same region) but my throughput is pretty slow: near 200/sec - it should be, at least, 800/sec.

If I remove the function that calls DynamoDB, the throughput increases to 1380/sec.

Here is the piece of code that access DynamoDB:

```
def findByKey(blacklistId: String): Option[Blacklist] = {
  val table = dynamoDB.getTable(TABLE_NAME)

  val spec = new GetItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("id", blacklistId).withConsistentRead(true)

  Try(table.getItem(spec)) match {
    case Success(item) if item != null =>
      val result: Blacklist = item.toJSON
      Some(result)
    case Success(item) if item == null =>
      None
    case Failure(e) =>
      Logger.error(e.getMessage, e)
      None
  }
}
```

Anyone knows how can i improve the performance on those requests?

Comment: First, you are using consistent read. Second, please check the provisioned throughout i.e. read capacity units of the table. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html... Also, you may need to check whether your partition key is properly designed to distribute the records to different partitions ...

Comment: It makes no difference using consistent read on tests and capacity units on table is 1500 - so the problem isn't on consistent read or provisioned throughout.

Comment: Are you making the requests in parallel? What does the calling code look like?